# Transfer a row from a table to another: jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to transfer a row which is selected with a jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 tbody tr").click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table2 tbody tr").click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

and the function which is supposed to transfer a row is this one:

```
 //fonction deplacement de tableau
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table-remove').click(function (e) {
         $("#table1 > tbody  > tr").each(function () {
             if($(this).attr('class')=="selected")
                {
                    $(".table2").append( $(this).parents('tr').clone());
                    $(this).parents('tr').detach();
                    console.log( $(this).parents('tr'));
                }
             });
    })
})
```

and I have some trouble with those 2 lines:

```
$(".table2").append( $(this).parents('tr').clone());
$(this).parents('tr').detach();
```

Do you know why?
Here is the HTML of the 2 tables:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped text-center table-hover table-condensed formatHTML5" id="table1">
 <thead>
 <tr>
     <th class="test">Ordre</th>
     <th style="display:none" class="text-center test3">Nom Pross</th>
     <th class="text-center test3">Verbe</th>
     <th class="text-center test4">Nom Opération</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Mini</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Maxi</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Total</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Mesure</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Retour</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Dépla</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Total</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Mesure</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Retour</th>
     <th style="display:none">TDA</th>
     <th  class="ellipsis text-center test">% Opera</th>
     <th style="display:none" class="text-center test2">Loc</th>
     <th class="text-center test2 ">Cible</th>
     <th class="text-center ">tktTime</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr th:each="LIST : ${LigneAvant}">
    <td  class="test" style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[0]}" ></td>
    <td  style="display:none" class="text-center test3 "  th:text="${LIST[1]}" ></td>
    <td  class="text-center test3 " style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[2]}" ></td>
    <td  class="text-center test4 " style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[3]}" ></td>  
    <td class="text-center test" style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[4]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[5]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[6]}" ></td>   
    <td  class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[7]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[8]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[9]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[10]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[11]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[12]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[13]}" ></td>   
    <td class="ellipsis test" th:text="${LIST[14]}" ></td>
    <td  style="display:none" class="ellipsis test2 text-center" th:text="${LIST[15]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis test2 text-center" th:text="${LIST[19]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[20]}" ></td>       
     </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped text-center table-hover table-condensed formatHTML5" id="table2">
  <thead>
 <tr>
     <th class="test">Ordre</th>
     <th style="display:none" class="text-center test3">Nom Pross</th>
     <th class="text-center test3">Verbe</th>
     <th class="text-center test4">Nom Opération</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Mini</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Maxi</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Total</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Mesure</th>
     <th style="display:none">Tps Retour</th>
     <th style="display:none">TDA</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Total</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Mesure</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Retour</th>
     <th class="text-center test">TDA</th>
     <th class="text-center test">Op</th>
     <th style="display:none" class="text-center test2">Loc</th>
     <th class="ellipsis test2 text-center">Cible</th>
     <th style="white-space:nowrap">tktTime</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr th:each="LIST : ${LigneApres}">
    <td  class="test" style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[0]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" class="text-center test3 " th:text="${LIST[1]}" ></td>
    <td  class="text-center test3 " style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[2]}" ></td>
    <td  class="text-center test4 " style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[3]}" ></td>  
    <td class="text-center test" style="white-space:nowrap" th:text="${LIST[4]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[5]}" ></td>   
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[6]}" ></td>    
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[7]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[8]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[9]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[10]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[11]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[12]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis text-center test" th:text="${LIST[13]}" ></td>  
    <td class="ellipsis test" th:text="${LIST[14]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" class="ellipsis test2 text-center" th:text="${LIST[15]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis test2 text-center" th:text="${LIST[19]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[20]}" ></td>       
     </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

I don't why the selected rows can't be appended to the other table. Do you have some clues?

Comment: You need to change $(".table2") to $("#table2"), because you don't have '.table2' class in table2 html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7o4vzs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via jQuery `insertAfter()` function.  check updated snippet below...

```js
$('table tr').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings('tr').removeClass('selected');
})
$('.remove').click(function(){
$('#table2 tbody').append('<tr>'+$('#table1 tr.selected').html()+'</tr>');
})
```

```css
.selected td {
    background: #ffffcf;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="remove">Remove Selected</button>
<h2>Table1</h2>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td>Row1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row6</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h2>Table2</h2>
<table id="table2">
<tr>
<td>Row21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row26</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i needed, i appreciate !

Comment: Do you know why it's duplicated the row in the other table ?

Comment: The row which i wanted to transfert move after ":tr:last-child" but also move as a duplicated row as the first row of the table, and i don't know why, i've just done this

Comment: `code //fonction deplacement du tableauAvant au tableauApres
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.table-bougesurApres').click(function (e) {
     $('#table1 tr.selected').insertAfter('#table2 tr:last-child');
    })
})  `

Comment: It only insert the first row, if i select many rows, only the first one is moved.Also after beeing moved, the row can't be selected anymore and i don't know why

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hf2otz6L/ here it worked, but on my j2e project it doesn't, rows are duplicated ... :'(

Comment: Ok I know why, it because my table is formated like this :
 <thead>
 <tr>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: I used .append() and everything worked :) here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7o4vzs/18/ thanks a lot